# Docker Cloud Autotest doesn't shows all services logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-cloud

I'm using [DockerCloud Repositories Autotest](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/automated-testing/) to test a service before image push.

This is my `docker-compose.test.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sut:
    build: .
    command: run_tests.sh
    depends_on:
      - test-dep
  test-dep:
    image: mongo:3.4
    tty: true
```

In the build logs I can see only `sut` service output, here but I need to see other services output for debug purposes when tests fail. 
I’ve also tried adding `tty: true` in the a service block without success. Mongo is just an example, any other image works in the same way.

How to show output of **all** *Autotest* containers in *Repositories* build logs?